# Why are Microsoft ODBC Driver 18.1.2.1 64bit installed in C:\Windows\system32?

Tags: sql-server, odbc, 64-bit, driver

I downloaded the lastest Microsoft ODBC Drivers for SQL Server and installed them on my development machine, after that I needed the path to the dll and was very much surprised to find the dll in system32 and not system.

Anybody having an idea why a 64bit component gets in stalled in a folder that explicitly is named system32 ?

Is this a bug or did I misunderstand something behind the naming concept they are using ?

Comment: This is more a question about why Windows stores its drivers in System32, not System. The answer is, probably, because it was easier. You'll actually note that the 64bit drivers goes into System32, and the 32bit in SysWOW64. System32 is where drivers native to the "bitness" of the system go, and SysWOW64 is where 32bit drivers on a 64 bit OS go.

Comment: The System32 directory contains 64-bit binaries on a 64-bit OS.

Comment: `System` was the only system directory back in the original 16 bit Windows days. The Win32 API for Windows NT and Windows 95 added `System32` for storage of 32 bit files. Why do you think 64 bit files should be installed `System`?

Comment: Because to me system should relate to the current bit version of the system. Otherwise they should have a System64 directory. I‘m again and again puzzled why 32/64 is such a mess under windows (and still in 2023). What is the naming concept of naming something system32 but storing 64bit stuff in there ? A name should have a meaning.